# Which Java API should I use for implementing certificate verification with OCSP support?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, jsse, java-security

There exist two java api references:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html

In the first one there's a description about X509TrustManager interface. I'm confused. Should I use that one for implementing x509 certificate verification or I must go through the second link? Which is the standard way of achieving my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) provide the documentation around the `CertPath class` how to implement your own certification path verification. So you have to handle the whole PKI certificate chain by your own 
(e.g. validation of signatures and certificates up to the root). Furthermore, it provide you with the information of the `PKIX` the default algorithm for certificate validation.

The [first link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) show how to use the `TrustManager` which uses the `PKIX` algorithm. Beside certificate path validation with `PKIX` contains the `TrustManager` more mechanism to establish `SSL/TLS` communications.

The `TrustManager`/`PKIX` algorithm also provide a mechanism for revocation (`CLR` and `OCSP`). To activate OCSP take a deeper look at the [first link section PKIX TrustManager Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#TrustManagerFactory).

> If the init(KeyStore ks) method is used, default PKIXParameters are
>   used with the exception that revocation checking is disabled. It can
>   be enabled by setting the system property
>   com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation to true.

And you have to set the security property `ocsp.enable` to true. So basically, you have nothing more to do then

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "true");
Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "true");
```

If you don't want to re-implement or exchange the verification chain mechanism which is provided already with the `TrustManager` and `PKIX` algorithm then you should definitely use the [first link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html). If you need more information about the `PKIX` algorithm, implement your own or do **just** certification validation and not establishing `TLS/SSL` communication then you should check the [second link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) .

Comment: I just need to do certificate verification and support revokation checking by OCSP? what do you mean full PKI?

Comment: @mdavid, please see my updated answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much, could you also hint where exactly I should put the OCSP part in trust manager?

Comment: But it seems more related to the second link than the first, I just don't know where to put this code as in case of TrustManager I don't have PKIXParameters

Comment: @mdavid, I have added more details to my answer.

Comment: and what about bounty-castle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129119/discussion-between-mdavid-and-paul-wasilewski).

Comment: @mdavid, sorry I don't have more time. Please raise up a new question regarding bounty castle. Because this is a bit out of topic.

Comment: one more question please, in case of second link if I don't use TLS/SSL then how should I obtain certificate chain?