# How to check with Java and OCSP that the certificate is not revoked

Tags: java, ocsp

How to check with Java and OCSP that the certificate is not revoked? For me the best choise would be use some programmatic solution, because I'm calling the OCSP check from the custom code. I want just call something like `OCSPChecker.checkCertificateRevocationStatus` method.

The Oracle has the internal `sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSP` class for this, but it's not good habit to use the internal class.

[This Stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821619/which-java-api-should-i-use-for-implementing-certificate-verification-with-ocsp) offers deep information about the issue, but further link resources [Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE)
Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) and [Java PKI Programmer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AppC) seem quite complicated.

So what is the easiest way to do the certificate revocation check programatically with OCSP and Java? I prefer basic public Java API solution, but also simple open source libraries could be used.

Comment: There is no function to check solely for OCSP or more generally revocation. The CertPath API checks for validity _including_ but not limited to nonrevocation, which _can_ (at least with the usual providers) include OCSP. Yes it is not trivial. But you don't need to care about JSSE: while that provides hooks for TrustManager and KeyManager (and more), the _default_ calls the same CertPath API you can, adding some SSL/TLS-specific checks. Although I recommend using doc newer than java 7, which was already obsolete in 2016.